# Using Windows Clipboard Image in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, winapi

I am trying to convert clipboard bitmap data to opencv Mat object using win32api.

I tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    OpenClipboard(NULL);

    HGLOBAL ClipboardDataHandle = (HGLOBAL)GetClipboardData(CF_DIBV5);
    if(ClipboardDataHandle){
        BITMAPINFOHEADER *BitmapInfoHeader = (BITMAPINFOHEADER *)GlobalLock(ClipboardDataHandle);
        if(BitmapInfoHeader){
            Mat mat(BitmapInfoHeader->biHeight, BitmapInfoHeader->biWidth, CV_8UC4);
            memcpy(mat.data, BitmapInfoHeader, GlobalSize(ClipboardDataHandle));
            cvtColor(mat, mat, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            threshold(mat, mat, 120, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
            imwrite("res.bmp", mat);
            GlobalUnlock(BitmapInfoHeader);
        }
    }
    
    CloseClipboard();
}
```

This worked with many problems.

This worked in most cases with the vertical flipping problem.

And when copying an image containing transparent pixel information, it aborted with the exit code 0xc0000374(A heap has been corrupted).

I think the problem is that the third parameter of Mat is fixed to CV_8UC4.

If you save it to a file and read it again, there's no problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    OpenClipboard(NULL);

    HGLOBAL ClipboardDataHandle = (HGLOBAL)GetClipboardData(CF_DIBV5);
    if(ClipboardDataHandle){
        BITMAPINFOHEADER *BitmapInfoHeader = (BITMAPINFOHEADER *)GlobalLock(ClipboardDataHandle);
        if(BitmapInfoHeader){

            SIZE_T ClipboardDataSize = GlobalSize(ClipboardDataHandle);
            INT PixelDataOffset = BitmapInfoHeader->biSize;
            if (BitmapInfoHeader->biSize == sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER))
            {
                if (BitmapInfoHeader->biBitCount > 8)
                {
                    if (BitmapInfoHeader->biCompression == BI_BITFIELDS)
                    {
                        PixelDataOffset += 3 * sizeof(RGBQUAD);
                    }
                    else if (BitmapInfoHeader->biCompression == 6)
                    {
                        PixelDataOffset += 4 * sizeof(RGBQUAD);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (BitmapInfoHeader->biClrUsed > 0)
            {
                PixelDataOffset += BitmapInfoHeader->biClrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD);
            }
            else
            {
                if (BitmapInfoHeader->biBitCount <= 8)
                {
                    PixelDataOffset += sizeof(RGBQUAD) << BitmapInfoHeader->biBitCount;
                }
            }

            BITMAPFILEHEADER BitmapFileHeader = {};
            BitmapFileHeader.bfType = 0x4D42;
            BitmapFileHeader.bfSize = (DWORD)(sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + ClipboardDataSize);
            BitmapFileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + PixelDataOffset;


            HANDLE FileHandle = CreateFileA("temp.bmp", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
            if (FileHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                DWORD dummy = 0;
                WriteFile(FileHandle, &BitmapFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dummy, NULL);
                WriteFile(FileHandle, BitmapInfoHeader, (DWORD)ClipboardDataSize, &dummy, NULL);
                CloseHandle(FileHandle);
            }

            GlobalUnlock(BitmapInfoHeader);
        }
    }
    
    CloseClipboard();
    Mat mat = imread("temp.bmp");
    cvtColor(mat, mat, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    threshold(mat, mat, 120, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    imwrite("res.bmp", mat);
}
```

This works very well. No flipping issues and no errors. But I don't want to use temporary files. Please help.

Comment: You are writing past the end of the allocated memory for your `mat`. `GlobalSize` returns the size of the *entire* memory object, not just the pixel data.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for your comments. If so, why doesn't the second code cause the problem? Also uses GlobalSize. (variable ClipboardDataSize)

Comment: Chances of corrupting the heap are far lower if you aren't actually writing to memory.

Answer (score 1):

I can't found solution yet.

Just I answer myself to because I found a temporary way after a lot of hard work.

I need much feedback because not confident with this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_DIBV5)){
        OpenClipboard(NULL);

        HGLOBAL clipboard = GetClipboardData(CF_DIBV5);

        if(clipboard){
            BITMAPV5HEADER* bitmapV5Header = (BITMAPV5HEADER*)GlobalLock(clipboard);

            if(bitmapV5Header){
                int type;
                switch(bitmapV5Header->bV5BitCount){
                    case 32:
                    {
                        type = CV_8UC4;
                        break;
                    }
                    case 24:
                    {
                        type = CV_8UC3;
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        type = -1;
                        std::cout << "no support" << std::endl;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(type != -1){
                    Mat tmp(bitmapV5Header->bV5Height, bitmapV5Header->bV5Width, type, (BYTE*)bitmapV5Header + (GlobalSize(clipboard) - bitmapV5Header->bV5SizeImage), bitmapV5Header->bV5SizeImage / bitmapV5Header->bV5Height); // data not copy
                    Mat mat;
                    flip(tmp, mat, 0); // flip with data copy
                    cvtColor(mat, mat, COLOR_BGR2GRAY); // just for test.
                    threshold(mat, mat, 80, 255, THRESH_BINARY);  // just for test.
                    imwrite("result.png", mat);
                }

                GlobalUnlock(clipboard);
            }

        }

        CloseClipboard();
    }
}
```

I think that there will be more cases where the "bV5BitCount" value is other than 24 and 32.

And I still don't know the cause of the vertical flipping problem.
But since I couldn't find a way to copy the data while using step or stride,
Using openCV, flipping and copying at the same time.

Comment: use `imdecode()` with a buffer where all other stays like with file

Comment: @Алексей Неудачин That seems like good information. I thought "imdecode" could only input from a file or "Mat" object. Can I use "imdecode" to read an image without going through a file?

Answer (score -1):

use `CreateFileMapping()` with `hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`
and then do .bmp stuff.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-createfilemappingw

but to be fair i'm not sure you could use opencv with this file.
you'll have `hFile` and idk whatever `GetFinalPathNameByHandle()` will work with it or not

But better use just `imdecode()` instead